# While loop runs continuously in Python, good input or bad?

Tags: python, input, error-handling, while-loop, break

I'm writing a code that asks the user for a percentage, and keeps asking until an acceptable input is entered by the user. However when I run this, the while loop does not break no matter what kind of input I enter.

Here is my code:

```
import math

while True:
    try:
        entered = float(raw_input("Please enter the velocity (as a percentage of the speed of light): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, an acceptable input was not entered. Try again.")
        continue

    if entered > 100:
        print("Sorry, a velocity greater than the speed of light cannot be used. Try again.")
        continue
    elif entered <= 0:
        print("Sorry, a percent cannot be negative. Try again.")
        continue
    else:
        #the percent entered is valid, break out of while loop
        break

print("Ship is traveling at ", entered, "% the speed of light.")
print("  ")

speedOfLight = 299792458                         #speed of light constant
percentage = entered / 100                       #turn entered percent into decimal
speed = speedOfLight * percentage                #actual speed (in m/s)         
denominator = math.sqrt(1 - (percentage ** 2))   #denominator of factor equation
factor =  1 / denominator                        #solve for given factor equation

shipWeight = 70000 * factor                      #given ship weight * factor
alphaCentauri = 4.3 / factor                     # given times divided by the factor
barnardsStar = 6.0 / factor
betelgeuse = 309 /factor
andromeda = 2000000 / factor

print("At this speed: ")
print("    Weight of the shuttle is ", shipWeight)
print("    Perceived time to travel to Alpha Centauri is ", alphaCentauri, " years.")
print("    Perceived time to travel to Barnard's Star is ", barnardsStar, " years.")
print("    Perceived time to travel to Betelgeuse is ", betelgeuse, " years.")
print("    Perceived time to travel to Andromeda Galaxy is ", andromeda, " years.")
```

Comment: Please take the time to fix the indenting so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is a little wonky, and the code never reaches the `break` statement because you `continue` the loop before then. Luckily, you can use and `else` keyword to make it work:

```
while True:
    try:
        entered = float(raw_input("Please enter the velocity (as a percentage of the speed of light): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, an acceptable input was not entered. Try again.")
        continue
    else: # no exception
        if entered > 100:
            print("Sorry, a velocity greater than the speed of light cannot be used. Try again.")
            continue
        elif entered <= 0:
            print("Sorry, a percent cannot be negative. Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            #the percent entered is valid, break out of while loop
            break
```

Comment: yeah my bad I always mess up the indenting when I enter code on this website. But thank you it worked like a charm!

Comment: @Clarisa once you get used to the indenting, python is one of the most well designed languages out there. Enjoy it :)

Answer (score 3):

You are checking the inputs of your data inside your `except`. You are never going to get inside your except unless the casting to `float` raises a `ValueError`.

You simply want to move your conditions outside of the `except` block, so you can check the data that passes the `float` casting:

```
while True:
    try:
        entered = float(input("Please enter the velocity (as a percentage of the speed of light): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, an acceptable input was not entered. Try again.")
        continue

    if entered > 100:
        print("Sorry, a velocity greater than the speed of light cannot be used. Try again.")
        continue
    elif entered <= 0:
        print("Sorry, a percent cannot be negative. Try again.")
        continue
    else:
        #the percent entered is valid, break out of while loop
        break
```

Comment: I think (hope) the editor messed that up because it's invalid syntax as written in the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the continues/breaks to make this work. You also will need to "import math" which will matter once you eventually break out of the while loop.

What you do need to do is watch the indention. The try/except were out of position -- if that reflects how the code was actually written that would account for your never ending while loop.

The below works as you desired with only indention fixes and "import math"

```
import math

valid = False

while not valid:
    try:
            entered = float(raw_input("Please enter the velocity (as a percentage of the speed of light): "))
    except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, an acceptable input was not entered. Try again.")
            continue

    if entered > 100:
        print("Sorry, a velocity greater than the speed of light cannot be used. Try again.")
    elif entered <= 0:
        print("Sorry, a percent cannot be negative. Try again.")
    else:
        #the percent entered is valid, break out of while loop
            valid = True

print("Ship is traveling at ", entered, "% the speed of light.")
print("  ")

speedOfLight = 299792458                         #speed of light constant
percentage = entered / 100                       #turn entered percent into decimal
speed = speedOfLight * percentage                #actual speed (in m/s)         
denominator = math.sqrt(1 - (percentage ** 2))   #denominator of factor equation
factor =  1 / denominator                        #solve for given factor equation

shipWeight = 70000 * factor                      #given ship weight * factor
alphaCentauri = 4.3 / factor                     # given times divided by the factor
barnardsStar = 6.0 / factor
betelgeuse = 309 /factor
andromeda = 2000000 / factor

print("At this speed: ")
print("    Weight of the shuttle is ", shipWeight)
print("    Perceived time to travel to Alpha Centauri is ", alphaCentauri, " years.")
print("    Perceived time to travel to Barnard's Star is ", barnardsStar, " years.")
print("    Perceived time to travel to Betelgeuse is ", betelgeuse, " years.")
print("    Perceived time to travel to Andromeda Galaxy is ", andromeda, " years.")
```